# How to get parsed / human-readable contract storage with tezos-node?

Tags: node, taquito, storage

How can I get human-readable contract storage data with `tezos-node`?

If I run a command like `curl -s http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1BGQR7t4izzKZ7eRodKWTodAsM23P38v7N/storage | jq` then I'll get something back like:

```
{
  "prim": "Pair",
  "args": [
    {
      "int": "541"
    },
    {
      "prim": "Pair",
      "args": [
        {
          "prim": "False"
        },
        {
          "prim": "False"
        },
        {
          "int": "2053016532"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "prim": "Pair",
      "args": [
        {
          "string": "KT1B5VTw8ZSMnrjhy337CEvAm4tnT8Gu8Geu"
        },
        {
          "string": "KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "int": "21326637"
    },
    {
      "int": "1535368503"
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, none of these fields are labeled with human-readable names.

However, if you [look at this contract on TzKT](https://tzkt.io/KT1BGQR7t4izzKZ7eRodKWTodAsM23P38v7N/storage/), TzKT has somehow inferred human-readable names for all the fields. Taquito is also able to infer human-readable names. Is there some way to do the same using `tezos-node`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like the way tzkt displays the storage of contracts, you should probably use their API instead of trying to get the information from a node.

If you want to redo the same work, the human-readable names used for the fields very probably come from the field annotations in the type of the storage. To get this type you can do `curl -s http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1BGQR7t4izzKZ7eRodKWTodAsM23P38v7N/ | jq .script.code[1].args`.